# 'Did/does' at head of subordinate phrase

Tags: subject-verb-inversion, style-manuals, emphasis, do-support

> [*He **does** have a sense of humour **does** Mr Marr*](https://books.google.es/books?id=w2NjCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA186&ots=LG0HLd6W7U&dq=%22He%20does%20have%20a%20sense%20of%20humour%20does%20Mr%20Marr%E2%80%94Nigel%20Williams%2C%201992%22&hl=es&pg=PA186#v=onepage&q=%22He%20does%20have%20a%20sense%20of%20humour%20does%20Mr%20Marr%E2%80%94Nigel%20Williams,%201992%22&f=false).
>
> Nigel Williams, 1992

Is this double use of **do** just doubly emphatic?

Secondly, why can't *do* be used similarly, for example with a plural proper noun?

Comment: You tagged "style-manuals," but this usage is colloquial. And sure, you could replicate with other subjects: "They do get about, do the widows Johnson." Analytically, I guess you could regard this construction as conflating multiple sentences or clauses for emphasis, as if an expanded form would be "Mr Marr has a sense of humor, yes he does."

Comment: ... 'Mr and Mrs Marr do like to have a joke, yes/so they do.' These are echo tags. Common in certain Anglophone regions, though perhaps becoming dated. It would sound too clumsy as 'Mr and Mrs Marr like to have a joke, do Mr and Mrs Marr'.